# .htaccess Rewrite for PDF file for different domains

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two domains, both domains need a pdf file that can be downloaded but have the same root:

1. http://www.domain.com/test.pdf -> should redirect to
   /domain_com/test.pdf
2. http://www.domain.eu/test.pdf -> should redirect to
   /domain_eu/test.pdf

I have seriously no idea or clue how to do this. Can someone explain me how this works in a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!domain_com/).+?\.pdf)$ domain_com/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!domain_eu/).+?\.pdf)$ domain_eu/$1 [L,NC]
```